# Formatted Hard drive and boot device not found

Tags: hard-drive, format

I installed my OS (Ubuntu 20.04)  in my M.2 SSD. That's why I thought it will bring no problem if I format my hard disk. When the format is done the computer was still running but the problem showed up after reboot. It said boot device not found. Help me.[After reboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Od16.jpg)

Comment: You probably wiped out a master boot record or a /boot directory or something similar.  If your system uses grub2, you will need to repair grub.  If it uses UEFI, you will need to repair your EFI directory.  But that's all I know without doing more research and without knowing which boot system your computer uses.

Comment: It uses UEFI.If i try to install OS again, will it solve my problem?

Comment: Probably the EFI partition ( usually mounted as /boot/efi ) was resident in your hard drive (Did you have any OS on your hard drive ? ) So first off you have to boot a live ISO and [create a new partition using GParted](https://technastic.com/create-and-resize-partitions-with-gparted/) (shouldn't be necessarily the first partition , so you can shrink one of your current partitions ) and [re-install grub on your SSD](https://linuxsuperuser.com/reinstall-grub2-efi-bootloader-ubuntu/)

Comment: @MD.YeasinAkbar There's a better solution than re-installing the OS which is quite cumbersome. See my comment above.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help.I learned a lot.